# Wrong output from an array

Tags: c, arrays, output

I've been running this for a couple of hours, and continue to get the wrong output, and can't seem to find out why. It seems as if everything should work, but I consistently get a weird character for the first time I implement this, and the tokens are not getting moved around in the way that they should be. This is just practice code, to be implemented in assembly language.

```
    char get_line(void){
  //Char array, buf space 80, int array, hold the numerical value,
  char arr[80];
  int int_arr[80];
  char arr_print[80];
  //Two points to compare whether the value in the given array changed.
  int compare;
  int compare_2;
  //Array points, indexes and size counter.
  int count = -1;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int k;

  gets(arr);//Unsafe version of code, but for this implementation negligible.

  while( (arr[i] != NULL) && (i < 80) && arr[i] != '\n'){
    //Runs through and sets the value based on specs, #'s =1, alpha =2, ...
    //For the comparison with the below code.
    if(isalpha(arr[i])){
      int_arr[i] = 2;// printf("%c: 2", arr[i]);
      compare = 2;

    }else if(isdigit(arr[i])){
      int_arr[i] = 1;// printf("%d: 1", arr[i]);
       compare = 1;

    }else if(arr[i] == '$'){
      int_arr[i] = 5;// printf("%c: 5", arr[i]);
      compare = 5;

    }else if(arr[i] == '#'){
      int_arr[i] = 6;// printf("%c: 6", arr[i]);
      compare = 6;

    }else if(arr[i] == '(' || arr[i] == ')' || arr[i] == ',' || 
        arr[i] == '.' || arr[i] == ':'){
      int_arr[i] = 4;// printf("%c: 4", arr[i]);
      compare = 4;

    }else if(arr[i] == '*' || arr[i] == '+' || arr[i] == '-' ||
        arr[i] == '/'){
      int_arr[i] = 3;//printf("%c: 3", arr[i]);
      compare = 3;

    }else if(isspace(arr[i]))
      int_arr[i] = 5;//Ignore the spaces in this implementation.
    /*
      Runs the comparison point to assure that the 
      tokens are matched up and grouped as needed.
    */     
    if(compare_2 == 0 || (compare != compare_2)){   
      if(compare_2 != 0){
    for(k=0; k<=j ;k++)
      printf("%c", arr_print[k]); 

    j=0;
      }    
      printf("\t\t%d \n", compare_2);
      compare_2 = compare; 

    }else if( isspace(arr[i]) == 0 ){
      arr_print[j] = arr[i];
      //      printf("\t\t\t\t\t%c  | %d\n", arr_print[j],j);
      j++;
    }

    i++;
    count++;
  }
  printf("\n\n");
  //Code for previous implementation in C  
  for(i=0; i<80 && arr[i] != NULL; i++)
    printf("%c", arr[i]);
  printf("\n");

  for(i=0; i< count+1; i++)
    printf("%d", int_arr[i]);
  printf("\n");

  if(i == 0 || count == -1) return '#';

  return arr[count];
}
```

Comment: You might want to start with initializing `compare` and `compare_2` to known values. At the very least, this would no longer have Undefined Behavior, so you can concentrate on the *actual* problem.

Comment: `while( (arr[i] != NULL) && (i < 80) && arr[i] != '\n'){` --> `while( i < 80 && arr[i] != '\0'){`

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications on some of those points, My heads still in the point of C++ where the values get initialized at 0 if undeclared. Thank you for that, and also in regards to the '\0' was getting an annoying error due to something before in the code when using it, most likely due to the use of gets... Thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you needed

Try this code

```
char get_line(void) 
{
  //Char array, buf space 80, int array, hold the numerical value,
  char arr[80];
  int int_arr[80];
  char arr_print[80];
  //Two points to compare whether the value in the given array changed.
  int compare=0;    
  int compare_2=0;
  //Array points, indexes and size counter.
  int count = -1;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int k = 0;
  int l = 0;  // I add an int l for 

  gets(arr);//Unsafe version of code, but for this implementation negligible.

  //while( (arr[i] != NULL) && (i < 80) && arr[i] != '\n'){
  while( i < 80 && arr[i] != '\0') 
  {
    //Runs through and sets the value based on specs, #'s =1, alpha =2, ...
    //For the comparison with the below code.
    if(isalpha(arr[i]))
    {
        int_arr[i] = 2;// printf("%c: 2", arr[i]);
        compare = 2;
    }
    else if(isdigit(arr[i]))
    {
        int_arr[i] = 1;// printf("%d: 1", arr[i]);
        compare = 1;
    }
    else if(arr[i] == '$')
    {
        int_arr[i] = 5;// printf("%c: 5", arr[i]);
        compare = 5;
    }
    else if(arr[i] == '#')
    {
        int_arr[i] = 6;// printf("%c: 6", arr[i]);
        compare = 6;
    }
    else if(arr[i] == '(' || arr[i] == ')' || arr[i] == ',' || arr[i] == '.' || arr[i] == ':')
    {
        int_arr[i] = 4;// printf("%c: 4", arr[i]);
        compare = 4;
    }
    else if(arr[i] == '*' || arr[i] == '+' || arr[i] == '-' || arr[i] == '/')
    {
        int_arr[i] = 3;//printf("%c: 3", arr[i]);
        compare = 3;
    }
    else if(isspace(arr[i]))
        int_arr[i] = 5;//Ignore the spaces in this implementation.
    /*
        Runs the comparison point to assure that the 
        tokens are matched up and grouped as needed.
    */     
    if(compare_2 == 0 || (compare != compare_2))
    {
        if(compare_2 != 0)
        {
            for(k=0; k<=j ;k++) 
                printf("%c", arr[l+k]);   // arr_print replaced by arr
            j=0;
            l+=k;  // int l to go through array arr
        }
        printf("\t\t%d \n", compare_2);
        compare_2 = compare; 
    }
    else if( isspace(arr[i]) == 0 )
    {
        arr_print[j] = arr[i];
        //printf("\t\t\t\t\t%c  | %d\n", arr_print[j],j);
        j++;
    }
    i++;
    count++;
  }

  printf("%c", arr[count]);        // Repeated code to print the last element
  printf("\t\t%d \n", compare_2);
  compare_2 = compare;

  printf("\n\n");
  //Code for previous implementation in C  
  for(i=0; i<80 && arr[i] != NULL; i++)
    printf("%c", arr[i]);
  printf("\n");

  for(i=0; i< count+1; i++)
    printf("%d", int_arr[i]);
  printf("\n");

  if(i == 0 || count == -1) return '#';

  return arr[count];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that code fragment, works as needed, now to see about implementing this as assembly language. I see where I went wrong on a few of the points as well, it's always the simple points that mess one up.